# azure's createBlockBlobFromLocalFile doesn't create blob on storage container

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm uploading recursively content folder for my site on blob storage.
Overall routine is quite simple:

1 - Drop container if exists ( runs good)

2 - Create container (runs ok, yet must tell that it's an iterative process that takes few  attempts)

3 - Run through the folder recursively and upload files as blob to the storage ( partially ok)

Third step runs blazing fast, but doesn't rise neither internal error nor calls my callback

Here is a code for the blob upload

```
upload: function( container, blobname, file ){
    var p = new Promise();
    this.service.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile( container, blobname, file, function( error ){
        if( error ){
            throw error;
        }
        console.log( "Uploaded file '"+ file +"' to container in '" + blobname + "'" );
        p.resolve();
    } );
    return p;
}
```

I must mention that none of other methods like **createBlockBlobFromStream** and others did work as well. I'm definitely doing it wrong, but I can't see what.

Comment: Does the function return or simply hang?  And when you say that the callback isn't being called, do you mean the callback posted, with the console log line or the callback in the promise?  Finally, have you tried using createBlockBlobFromLocalFile (or other methods like createBlockBlobFromStream) without Promise and instead using the standard async callback pattern?

Comment: 1 - _Does the function return or simply hang_ - It returns speed summary
2 - _callback isn't being called_ - Callback for the createBlockBlobFromLocalFile is not called, the one containing logging statement.
3 - _try without Promise_ - didn't try yet, but i tried to upload file without visiting folders recursively. It worked out. As for promise - I'm not sure it can mess with azure library code since it's independent module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my mistake and It's where you're right Emily. Games with promises didn't went well.

I forgot to return promise from folders process method and thus finished the overall task long before azure response.

```
blobsService.cleanContainer( container ).
             then( blobsService.createContainer.bind( blobsService ) ).
             then( function(){
                   var folders = data.rootFolder.split( path.sep );
                   !!!return!!! blobsService.processFolder( container, data.rootFolder, folders[ folders.length - 1 ] );
             }).
             then( resolver );
```